# Why shouldn't I easily implement a join datatype relationship similar to Elasticsearch's parent-child

Tags: elasticsearch-6

What are the benefits of using ElasticSearch parent/child join vs just storing customn 'parent-id' property for children documents.

I do understand that parent-child gives built-in queries (has_child, has_parent) for accessing parents/children from each other. are there any other considerations?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer in an old Elasticsearch forum answer by mr.math.roy@gmail.com

> Because you can execute queries against the parents and have the children
>   of the matching documents returned or vice versa. It is much more powerful
>   than simple filtering of a field.

this was very important to me, for example, when wanting to delete a parent document, so instead of looking for its children afterwards and deleting them as well, i just put their data in the has_child query.